# Printing same rows twice in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using this query

```
SELECT 
    [SCORECARD_NAME], [SCORE_NAME],
    [TOTAL_ROWS], [VALID_PERCENTAGE], [INVALID_ROWS] 
FROM 
    {table_name}
```

and I'm getting the result twice. I'm not getting why its happening like that 
what is the solution for this?

[image]

Comment: The two answers below may fix the immediate problem, but I was wondering if perhaps you could add a `WHERE` clause to the query, acting on _other_ columns, which would leave you not having the "duplicate" problem.  Can you show us your table definition?

Comment: The reason the row appears to be selected twice is because you have two rows in the table that are exactly the same (twice).  If that is not want you want then delete one of the rows.

Comment: It's displayed twice because you have two identical data in the table.

Comment: There's also the question if you did `JOIN` another table to get this result. `JOIN` statements will produce multiple results of a single table row when it is matched by multiple rows in the joined table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SELECT DISTINCT`, or here is an option using a CTE with a window function:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT [SCORECARD_NAME], [SCORE_NAME], [TOTAL_ROWS], [VALID_PERCENTAGE],[INVALID_ROWS],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [SCORECARD_NAME]
                           ORDER BY [SCORECARD_NAME]) AS DuplicateCount
    FROM Table_Name      
)

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE DuplicateCount = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want rows with same entries to be displayed once then use `distinct`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [SCORECARD_NAME], [SCORE_NAME], [TOTAL_ROWS],
    [VALID_PERCENTAGE], [INVALID_ROWS] 
FROM 
    {table_name};
```

Let me know in case of any queries.